# WAMP SSL - LOCALHOST and connection problem from another VM

Tags: apache, ssl, localhost, virtual-machine, wamp

I set up 2 VMS connected to each others , ping is working on both machine.
After that , I set up a WAMP serveur on machine 1 and managed to configure SSL on it. It's working on local host as described on this tutorial.

https://zuziko.com/tutorials/how-to-enable-https-ssl-on-wamp-server/

Now my problem is i need to be able to connect from the browser of VM 2 on the wamp server with SSL.

That's where i have a problem.

From Vm2 when i connect to VM 1 ( 192.168.56.10:8080) it's working
when i connect to 192.168.56.10:443 i have a bad request.

I am missing something .. can someone point me out where to look ?

thank you very much

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBg3V.png)

Comment: Also it would help if you share a piece of code at least from the web client.

Comment: hi thanks for the answer, i dont know what piece of code to show first as there is many files implyed